# UITableView not appearing properly using constraints

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having problems displaying this `UITableView` under the `UIImageView`. It does this weird thing, where you can't see the table or anything at all, however when you scroll up or down, you can see the blue cell appear in the 40px high `UITableView`.

```
class TvDetailHeader: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    private let contributorCellId = "contributorCellId"

    let thumbnailImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "stranger things poster"))
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()

    let contributorTableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.backgroundColor = .blue
        return tableView
    }()

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: contributorCellId, for: indexPath) as! ContributorCell
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()

        contributorTableView.delegate = self
        contributorTableView.dataSource = self

        contributorTableView.register(ContributorCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: contributorCellId)

        backgroundColor = .white

        addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
        addSubview(contributorTableView)

        thumbnailImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
        thumbnailImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        thumbnailImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        thumbnailImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90).isActive = true

        contributorTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thumbnailImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        contributorTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        contributorTableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width).isActive = true
        contributorTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    }
}

class ContributorCell: UITableViewCell  {

    let cellView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(cellView)

        backgroundColor = .blue

        cellView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        cellView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        cellView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        cellView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.height).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you registering the cell?

Comment: Sorry, found it!

Comment: Where do you create the constraints? In a `.xib` file?